# Frequent crash when launching default RealityKit project

Tags: swift, xcode, realitykit

I'm facing an issue where when opening the RealityKit template from Apple in Xcode 11.5, the app will crash on an iPad Pro 11" (2020) with a confusing error.

The error is

> com.apple.arkit.capture (35): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffffc)

The last message in the console is

> 2020-05-26 12:28:12.740185+0930 BlankAR[4276:154461] [Sensor] ARDepthSensor (AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTimeOfFlightCamera - Back) (0x141f26290): capture session dropped jasper frame: 4570.047651, LateData

There isn't really any more info to provide. It's Apple's default Augmented Reality template in Xcode.

Comment: You'll need to add some code if you seriously would like to get any help

Comment: This is without any code. This is on launching the default template.

Comment: Did you have any progress on that?

Comment: Apple just released iOS 14.4. Let's hope that they stabilized RealityKit. Otherwise, it's not usable.